# AWS CLI Ouput formats to SPLUNK

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, splunk, amazon-kinesis

I'm using the AWS CLI to get some Kinesis metrics - part of that I'm able to specify the output format as one of the below: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration-format

> Output Format
>
> The Default output format specifies how the results are formatted. The
>   value can be any of the values in the following list. If you don't
>   specify an output format, json is used as the default.
>
> ```
> json – The output is formatted as a JSON
> ```
>
> string.
>
> yaml – The output is formatted as a YAML
>
> string. (Available in the AWS CLI version 2 only.)
>
> text – The output is formatted as multiple lines of tab-separated
>   string values. This can be useful to pass the output to a text
>   processor, like grep, sed, or awk.
>
> table – The output is formatted as a table using the characters +|- to
>   form the cell borders. It typically presents the information in a
>   "human-friendly" format that is much easier to read than the others,
>   but not as programmatically useful.

I've tried TEXT as that seems the most reasonable for splunk but I think the line separated data is messing up splunks ingest:

```
METRICDATARESULTS   iteratorAgeMilliseconds itagemillis PartialData
METRICDATARESULTS   readProvisionedThroughputExceeded   itagemillis PartialData
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:21:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:20:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:19:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:18:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:17:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T20:16:00+00:00
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
METRICDATARESULTS   writeProvisionedThroughputExceeded  itagemillis PartialData
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T19:36:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T19:35:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T19:34:00+00:00
TIMESTAMPS  2020-04-15T19:33:00+00:00
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
VALUES  0.0
```

Any thoughts on either the AWS or splunk side on how best to handle ingesting this data ?

here's the CLI command  `aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --start-time 16:29 --end-time 23:59 --metric-data-queries file://metric-data-queries.json --output text`
and contents of metric-data-queries.json

```
[
  {
    "Id": "iteratorAgeMilliseconds",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  },
  {
    "Id": "readProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "ReadProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  },
    {
    "Id": "writeProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "WriteProvisionedThroughputExceeded",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  },
    {
    "Id": "putRecordSuccess",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "PutRecord.Success",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  },
    {
    "Id": "putRecordsSuccess",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "PutRecords.Success",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  },
    {
    "Id": "getRecordsSuccess",
    "MetricStat": {
      "Metric": {
        "Namespace": "AWS/Kinesis",
        "MetricName": "GetRecords.Success",
        "Dimensions": [
          {
            "Name": "StreamName",
            "Value": "test.dev.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Period": 1,
       "Stat": "Sum",
        "Unit": "Count"
    },
    "Label": "itagemillis",
    "ReturnData": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Does Kinesis forward to logs to S3? Can you share the cli command as well ?

Comment: added to main question

Answer (score 0):

You will find that Splunk handles JSON pretty well out of the box, so I would recommend using that over the other options. You may need to set the `KV_MODE=JSON` for the sourcetype you ingest, but it should do it by default.

See more here for example, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Automatickey-valuefieldextractionsatsearch-time

You can also look at using the Splunk Apps to integrate with AWS, such as the Splunk Add-on for AWS, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1876/ , and the Splunk Add-On for Amazon Kinesis Firehose, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3719/

Comment: I tried json but it’s having an issue parsing out all of time stamps and values as individual events. It gives the entire json one time stamp

Comment: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/289520/how-to-split-a-json-array-into-multiple-events-wit.html

You may be able to BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE={"Id"